# how do you get sbt web plugin to work with a .scala config

Tags: scala, jetty, lift, sbt

I'm currently getting the error

> Plugin classpath does not exist for plugin definition at
>   file:/C:/project_root/project/

from the below files.
Does anyone know how to configure the web plugin properly for a lift project with .scala config?

---

plugin/Build.scala:

```
import com.github.siasia.PluginKeys._
import com.github.siasia.WebPlugin._
import sbt._
import Keys._

object BuildSettings {
  val buildOrganization = "dualitystudios"
  val buildVersion      = "0.1"
  val buildScalaVersion = "2.9.1"

  val buildSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq (
    organization := buildOrganization,
    version      := buildVersion,
    scalaVersion := buildScalaVersion
  )
}

object Dependencies {

    val liftVersion = "2.4"
    val logbackVer = "0.9.26"


    val lift_webkit = "net.liftweb" %% "lift-webkit" % liftVersion % "compile"
    val lift_mapper = "net.liftweb" %% "lift-mapper" % liftVersion % "compile"
    //val jetty = "org.mortbay.jetty" % "jetty" % "6.1.26" % "test"
    val junit = "junit" % "junit" % "4.7" % "test"
    val testing_tools = "org.scala-tools.testing" %% "specs" % "1.6.9" % "test"
    val logbackclassic = "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic"  % logbackVer
    val dbConnector = "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.2.147"
    val selenium = "org.seleniumhq.selenium" % "selenium-java" % "2.21.0"
    val mysql = "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.19"
    val jetty = "org.mortbay.jetty" % "jetty" % "6.1.22" % "test"

    val liftAuth = RootProject(uri("git://github.com/keynan/LiftAthentication.git"))
}


object Resolvers {
    val scala_testing = "Scala Testing" at "http://mvnrepository.com/artifact"
    def resolve_all = Seq(scala_testing)
}

object LiftProject extends Build {

    import Dependencies._;
    import BuildSettings._;
    import Resolvers._;

    lazy val JavaNet = "Java.net Maven2 Repository" at "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    //lazy val sbtWeb = uri("git://github.com/siasia/xsbt-web-plugin")



    lazy val main = Project (
    "xxxxxx",
    file ("."),

    settings = buildSettings ++ Seq (
            resolvers := resolve_all, 
            libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
                lift_webkit,
                lift_mapper,
                jetty,
                junit,
                testing_tools,
                logbackclassic,
                dbConnector,
                selenium,
                mysql
            )
        ) ++ webSettings

  ) dependsOn(liftAuth)
}
```

project/project/Build.scala:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object PluginDef extends Build {

        val jetty = "org.mortbay.jetty" % "jetty" % "6.1.22" 

            override lazy val projects = Seq(root)
            lazy val root = Project(
            "plug", 
            file("."), 
            settings = Seq(
                libraryDependencies ++= Seq(jetty))
        ) dependsOn( sbtWeb )

        lazy val sbtWeb = uri("git://github.com/siasia/xsbt-web-plugin")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `./project/project/Build.scala` with `./project/plugins.sbt` containing:

```
 libraryDependencies <+= sbtVersion(v => "com.github.siasia" %% "xsbt-web-plugin" % (v+"-0.2.11"))
```

Comment: I swear I tried that. Eh, it worked this time. Thank you muchly